# Combiming two select statemen sql

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I have following DB:
[image]

And I want to get Total profit of all Markets. This is total price of purchases - total number of salary you paid for employee.

So I have such queries:
I get sum of all Purchases for each Market

```
SELECT
    Markets.Title,
    SUM(Purchase.TotalPrice) sum
FROM Purchase
INNER JOIN Employees ON Purchase.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID
INNER JOIN Markets ON Employees.Market_ID = Markets.Market_ID
GROUP BY Markets.Title
```

In another query I get total sum of salary Market paid:

```
SELECT
    Markets.Title,
    SUM(Employees.Salary) sum
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Markets ON Employees.Market_ID = Markets.Market_ID
GROUP BY Markets.Title
```

But I am confused how to combine this queries in order to get profit of each market(sum of all orders - sum of all salary).
Can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
      m.Title
    , e.TotalSalary
    , e.TotalPrice
FROM dbo.Markets m
JOIN (
    SELECT
          e.Market_ID
        , TotalSalary = SUM(e.Salary)
        , TotalPrice = SUM(p.TotalPrice)
    FROM dbo.Employees e
    JOIN (
        SELECT Employee_ID, TotalPrice = SUM(TotalPrice)
        FROM dbo.Purchase
        GROUP BY Employee_ID
    ) p ON p.Employee_ID = e.Employee_ID
    GROUP BY e.Market_ID
) e ON e.Market_ID = m.Market_ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I'll try to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Something like.........

```
SELECT SUB_Q.Title, SUM(SUB_Q.Tot) FROM 
(
  SELECT Markets.Title, sum(Purchase.TotalPrice) as Tot
  FROM Purchase 
  INNER JOIN Employees ON Purchase.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID 
  INNER JOIN Markets ON Employees.Market_ID = Markets.Market_ID
  GROUP BY Markets.Title
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Markets.Title, sum(Employees.Salary) as Tot
  FROM Employees 
  INNER JOIN Markets ON Employees.Market_ID = Markets.Market_ID
  GROUP BY Markets.Title
) SUB_Q
GROUP BY SUB_Q.Title
```

Comment: You need UNION ALL because if by chance bothe titles and totals are the same one will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

just add the UNION keyword between the two SELECT

see here for detail about UNION : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180026%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I need to have Profit column with (sum of all orders - sum of all salary), but UNION just makes them in a one column